# Xamarin Mac Hardware Performance with older refurbished hardware

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, hardware

I am just about to start working on iOS side of my application, and then move onto Android and Windows Mobile perhaps, but I do not own a mac and I have read mixed reviews on Mac in Cloud for me to decide against it.

As far as the hardware, I found a refurbished OS10 Macbook on Newegg for around $200 Canadian, and I was wondering if anyone has used Xamarin with the networked Mac Agent system on this old of hardware. It seems to be the cheapest way to 'start' anyway, and I wanted to know what kind of performance there is on such old hardware. Will I be waiting for hours to compile basic software :P

Here is the description of the hardware in question:

```
Apple Grade C Laptop MacBook MC516LL/A-C
Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 (2.40 GHz)
2 GB Memory
250 GB HDD
13.3" Display
Mac OS X
```

Comment: You would need to at least upgrade the ram to 4GB (8gb would be better, that model does support up to 16gb). Core 2 Duo are old-school as you know and will not provide blazing fast compiles and sim work, but it would be functional since it supports the latest version of Xcode (Xcode 9.0b currently requires **at least** macOS 10.12.4). Build times; hours? no but you will be looking at a few minutes for a clean/rebuild for a debug config, longer for release builds and even more for LLVM enabled release builds.

Comment: FYI: Core 2 Duo is a no-go for accelerated Android emulators (Qemu-based AVD) unless you are looking at running on API19 or older emulators on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be slow. But how slow it is cannot be tell. Because slow is something you need to feel.

Also, one more thing you will need to consider is whether the old mac can upgrade to Sierra OS or not. This is because latest Xcode 8.3 will only able to install on Sierra OS. Without Xcode 8.3, you will need to downgrade xamarin version too. This is much more troublesome.

Comment: Hmm didn't know that. Thank you.